# UITabBar changing each time to a new tab, without scrolling to middle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I want to create an tabBar with 15 items that can be scroll right-left and stop in the middle and not just scrolling each time all the 5 items (320 every time)

I found a code and changed it for displaying 5 items, but when i'm scroll it, all the tab changed and the next tab with 5 items shown, and so on...

```
- (id)initWithItems:(NSArray *)items {

         self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 411.0, 320.0, 49.0)];
         if (self) {
        self.pagingEnabled = YES;
        self.delegate = self;

        self.tabBars = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

        float x = 0.0;

        for (double d = 0; d < ceil(items.count / 5.0); d ++) {
            UITabBar *tabBar = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0.0, 320.0, 49.0)];
            tabBar.delegate = self;

            int len = 0;

            for (int i = d * 5; i < d * 5 + 5; i ++)
                if (i < items.count)
                    len ++;

            tabBar.items = [items objectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(d * 5, len)]];
            [self addSubview:tabBar];
            [self.tabBars addObject:tabBar];
            [tabBar release];
            x += 320.0;
        }

        self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(x, 49.0);
    }
    return self;
}
```

How can i create a **'rubber effect'** so i can be stop on the 7 item for example.

Comment: You question is not clear. What is a "rubber effect"?

Comment: So you won't change every time 5 items, you can scroll for example 3 items to left without changing all the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use a different design than the one you quote. If you look at the code carefully you will notice that for each 5 items **a new tab bar is created**. Clearly, the functionality that you hope for is not feasible with this setup.

The alternative would be to rewrite this with your own `UIScrollView`. It could be challenging to get exactly the look and feel of the `UITabBar`, but perhaps that is not such an important constraint. Rather, you would be free to implement your very own design that harmonizes with the look of your app.

Comment: Do you have an example of an UIScrollView with some items? Its OK if it wont be like UITabBar, i will design it...

Comment: Really *any* UIScrollView. Just look at the docs. Set the `contentSize`, insert your buttons or images at the appropriate places, and then you can set the `contentOffset` to show the desired position. With `pagingEnabled` you will have your "rubber effect" (if I understand it right).